# Does there exist a submersion $f: R^n\rightarrow R^m$ ($n \geq m$)?

Tags: differential-geometry

Does there exist a submersion $f: R^n\rightarrow R^m$ ($n \geq m$)?
 I want to know the existence.

Answer (score 2):

Since $T\mathbb{R}^n$ has dimension $n$, and $T\mathbb{R}^m$ has dimension $m$, such a submersion can exist only if $m\leq n$. You can easily check that any projection on an $m$-dimensional plane in $\mathbb{R}^n$ gets the job done if that's the case.

Answer (score 0):

$(x_1,\dots,x_n)\mapsto(x_1,\dots,x_m)$

Comment: I am still confused. I want to know that, for a random data set $X \in R^n$, does there exist a submersion $f$ such that $f(X) \in R^m (m<=n)$.

Comment: @user91666, I cannot make sense of your comment ;-/